# Matlab Graphical Display Issues

Tags: ssh, fedora, ubuntu-14.04, matlab

I'm working on Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm accessing Matlab throught ssh (-X) on distant machine which run on fedora 20.

Few days ago I had to change my computer for a new one with a CPU/iGPU i5-6200U(Intel HD Graphics 5200). 
Since then I got this error:

```
 X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

 Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)

 Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)

 Value in failed request:  0x0

 Serial number of failed request:  18

 Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

And this is what my screen looks like:

http://hpics.li/70acb7f

I triyed to follow this solution:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/241374-libgl-error-persists-and-i-ve-tried-everything

but it didn't worked. Any help would be welcomed :)

PS: I installed the lastest graphical drivers from intel website but the problem remains

Matlab version: R2015a

**Update:** I tried with another machine with iGPU Intel HD Graphics 5500 under Ubuntu 14.04 and the result is the same.

Comment: Is it a 3rd party IDE?

Comment: No it's the official Matlab on linux made by MathWorks. I have an academic license from my university.

Comment: up please, I really need it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I enventually find the solution on this blog

https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/random-disappearing-letters/

if anyone is interested. This problem of display is more general and is related to Intel drivers on Ubuntu.